# Unable to pair multiple devices like my mouse and headset via bluetooth UBUNTU 21.04

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, headset

I am unable to pair my Bluetooth mouse and headset on same time in UBUNTU 21.04, If my mouse is paired then my Bluetooth headset is not pairing it is showing connected but not working, only one device is working at a time. please help me to fix this I am getting really annoyed by this.